# Anonymous functions with parameters

Tags: scala

When you see code that follows this pattern:

```
def index = Action { request =>
  // ..
}
```

Action trait: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L65

When looking at this code, how would you know that the request object is available to use within the code block? (is there a intellij shortcut for this?)

Can someone please create a miniature example of where you can mimic this pattern so I can understand how this works, and if you can explain in technical terms what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

The `Action` *trait* is not of interest here. Instead, because the body of the `index` method must be a *value*, not a *type*, you are looking at the `Action` *object*. You can learn more about objects [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html). Let's first simplify the syntax by removing syntactic sugar, i.e. making the program behave the same but with simpler constructs. If you try to call an object as if it were a method, what really happens is that `.apply` is inserted for you by the compiler:

```
def index = Action.apply((request) => {
  // ..
})
```

This may be more familiar; the `apply` method is being called on the `Action` object, passing a lambda function that takes a request. And obviously, an argument to a lambda is always available within that lambda. That's the point of them.

The lambda in this case is also known as a *callback*. A simple example that clarifies these features follows:

```
object WithAnswer {
  def apply(f: Int => Unit): Unit =
    f(42)
}

def printAnswer() = WithAnswer { answer =>
  println(answer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes you are passing a request to the lambda and therefore you can use it inside of the lamba I go tthat.  But how do you know which parameters are available?  Can IntelliJ tell me this easily or?

Comment: in your example, you have the parameter 'answer', what is that?

Comment: It is the integer that `WithAnswer.apply` passes to the lambda.

Comment: I just find it wierd, because the integer is hard coded (42) instead of being passed in as a parameter in the WithAnswer block.

Comment: How could you pass the integer from within your block?

Comment: Ok sorry, so this is when you want to expose the parameter of the apply method to the lambda, now I got it sorry.   But what if you also want to pass something from the block to the apply, is that possible?

Comment: @coolbreeze the `apply` method can use the return value of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This is called as `Loan pattern`

`withWriter` creates a writer for the user and then ensures the resource (writer) is properly closely after using.

All that user has to do is just use the `writer` and write something to the file

```
def withWriter(file: File)(f: Writer => Unit): Unit = {
  val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
  try {
    f(writer)
  } finally {
    writer close
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
 withWriter(new File("some_fix.txt") { writer =>
   writer println("write something")
 }
```

Comment: are you sure it is a loan pattern since that would be definitely relevant to resource management? i haven't read play source, but [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions) only mentions it accepts a function